# Having troubles with a particular Linq-To-Entity expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm still learning the ropes for Entity expressions, and I have this SQL query that I would like to implement into a Entity expression, the query is:

```
SELECT classname,abbreviation, cid
            FROM [db].[dbo].[classes] AS c
            WHERE c.cid IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT(CID)
                FROM [db].[dbo].[CDS]
                WHERE 
                        sid = '1'
                        AND
                        did = '24'
                    )
            ORDER BY abbreviation, classname
```

How would I go about implementing that query into an Entity expression?

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression would be :

```
context.Classes.Where(C => 
                (context.CDS.Where(CD => CD.sid == "1" && CD.did == "24")
                .Distinct(CD => CD.CID)).Contains(C.CID))
                .Select(C => new { 
                                    className = C.className, 
                                    abbreviation = C.abbreviation, 
                                    cid = C.cid 
                                 });
```

Hope this will help !!